# How to draw a circle in GNU Octave

Tags: octave, computational-geometry

In [Matlab you can draw a circle by just specifying the center and the radius](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/03/21/drawing-a-circle/) like this:

```
R = 10;
Center = [5,8];
circle(Center,R,1000,'b-');
hold on
plot(Center(1),Center(2),'g.')
```

The same code for MatLab won't work for GNU Octave. What octave code would draw a circle given a center x,y coordinates and a radius?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
t = linspace(0,2*pi,100)'; 
circsx = r.*cos(t) + x; 
circsy = r.*sin(t) + y; 
plot(circsx,circsy);
```

Comment: can you provide a complete example also stating the version of octave you are using?

Comment: a complete example for Octave 3.2.4: http://dp4j.sf.net/resources/circles.m. This is how it looks like: http://screencast.com/t/RN2hny4YKX

Answer (score 10):

Using the octave extra package octave-geometry you can use the function [drawCircle](http://octave.sourceforge.net/geometry/function/drawCircle.html) as

```
drawCircle(x_position, y_position, radius)
```

1. Download the package from https://octave.sourceforge.io/geometry/
2. In Octave:

   - `pkg install path_to_file.tar.gz`
   - `pkg load geometry`

Answer (score 4):

If you would like a reusable function, here's one possibility:

```
function [h, hc] = circles(x,y,r,cmrk)
% CIRCLES   plot 2-D circles, given a set of center coordinates and radii.
%
% Description:
%
%   Plot 2-D circles, given a set of center coordinates and radii. Values
%   can be vectors or matrices, as long as dimensions are consistent. If
%   a marker type (e.g. '+') is also given, circle centers will be marked
%   with it. The function returns a vector of handles for each circle and
%   a handle for all the center markers, if plotted.

assert(size(x)==size(y), 'Mismatching sizes')
assert(size(y)==size(r), 'Mismatching sizes')

if (nargin==4)
    hc = scatter(x,y,[],[],cmrk);
end
axis([min(x-r) max(x+r) min(y-r) max(y+r)], 'equal');

a = linspace(0, 2*pi, 12);
dx = sin(a); dy = cos(a);
hold on
for i=1:numel(x);
    h(i) = line(x(i)+dx*r(i), y(i)+dy*r(i));
end
hold off
```

Here's an example of usage:

```
x = 0:.1:2*pi; y = sin(x); r = rand(size(x))*.3;
circles(x, y, r, '+')
```

Comment: why not contribute this function to Octave? It's well written and may be useful for future users. I would just rename it to be compatible with Matlab.

Answer (score 3):

**How to draw a circle in gnu octave version 3.8:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
octave> x = -1:0.01:1;
octave> y = (1 - x .^ 2) .^ 0.5;
octave> plot(x,y, "linewidth", 4, x,-y, "linewidth", 4);
```

**Verbalization:**

Create a list between -1 and 1 in increments of `.01` to represent the x axis.   The y axis is the diameter of the circle minus the value at each index of x squared, all raised to the `0.5`.

Plot x and y (blue), which gives the upper half of the circle, then plot x to -y, which inverts the top (green), creating the bottom half of the circle.

### Alternatively, use linspace:

[image]

**Code:**

```
octave> r = 1;
octave> t = linspace(0,2.*pi,1);
octave> circsx = r.*cos(t) + x;
octave> circsy = r.*sin(t) + y;
octave> plot(circsx,circsy, "linewidth", 4, circsx, -circsy, "linewidth", 4);
```

**Verbalization:**

Draws a circle.

Answer (score 1):

**Plot a circle in GNU Octave:**

```
x = -3:0.01:3;
y = (4 - x .^ 2) .^ 0.5;
figure; plot(x,y); hold on; plot(x,-y);
```

That should draw a circle having an equation x^2 + y^2 = 4;

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in function in the package "geometry" that can be used to draw different geometric shapes. Here is the code for a circle:

```
pkg load geometry
drawCircle (x0, y0, r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ocatve have several way to draw circle,that is one of easy way.

```
pkg load geometry
x=0;
y=0; #center point ordered pair
r1=10; #radius of circule
h1=drawCircle(x,y,r1);
```

if you want drow more circle over,

```
hold on;
r2=8;
h2=drawCircle(x,y,r2);
```

[image]

another way is

```
angle=linspace(0,2*pi,360);

r=5; #radius

x=2;

y=5; #x and y is hear center point 

horizantalValue=r*cos(angle)+x;

verticalValue=r*sin(angle)+y;

plot(verticalValue,horizantalValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
radius = 5;
x = cosd([0:360]) * radius;
y = sind([0:360]) * radius;
plot(x,y)
```