# Drawing an arc in octave

Tags: octave, geometry, algebra

I am new to octave and trying to draw a arc with parameters (theta1, theta2, xc,yc,r). I searched it online but couldn't get it. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw a circle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971467/how-to-draw-a-circle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no built-in function for this, you can do it quite simply:

```
theta = linspace(theta1, theta2);
x = r*cos(theta) + xc;
y = r*sin(theta) + yc;
plot(x, y)
```

You might need to do

```
axis equal
```

to get the aspect ratio right.